# Send Authentication header with PHP

Tags: php, xml, api

I am very new to APIs but I need to send an Authentication header with my request for an XML data file.

I have the following script that processes the XML file when it is returned

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://api.familysearch.org/reservation/v1/person/L81G-M81") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

print_r($xml->persons->person->baptism);
?>
```

The only problem is that it returns status code 401 Unauthenticated to my request.

Can someone please tell me how to send an Authentication header with my request? I am using an access token for authentication. Again, I am new to using APIs and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl to send the header something like this:

```
$service_url = 'https://api.familysearch.org/reservation/v1/person/L81G-M81';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

$curl_res = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_res);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

Verify that you have enabled the openssl module for the ssl connection.

**Edit:**

to send a header with token here is an OAuth example.

```
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$accesstoken;

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
```

To test the command you can use the command line:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.example.com
```

Comment: When I try that it returns NULL. I am trying to authenticate with an access token if that helps any.